# Majority Element using divide-and-conquer algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

everyone!
An element of a sequence of length n is called a majority element if it appears in the sequence strictly more than n/2 times.

The goal in this code problem is to check whether an input sequence contains a majority element.

I'm trying to solve this problem, using merge sorting algorithm

My strategy:

1. Sort sequence, using merge algorithm
2. Find an occurrence of each element in sorted list. If it is more than n/2, return 1. As the list is sorted I want to go through the list, and if next element is differs from previous one counter stops and compare it with n/2

   ```
   def merge(left,rigt):
       result = []
       i = j = 0
       while i < len(left) and j < len(rigt):
           if left[i] <= rigt[j]:
               result.append(left[i])
               i += 1

           else:
               result.append(rigt[j])
               j += 1

       result += left[i:]
       result += rigt[j:]

       return result

   def merge_sort(a):
   if len(a) <= 1:
       return a

   middle = len(a)//2

   left = a[:middle]
   right = a[middle:]

   left = merge_sort(left)
   right = merge_sort(right)

   return list(merge(left,right))

   def get_major_element(a,n):

   k = 1

   for i in range(0,len(a)-1):
       if a[i] == a[i+1]:
           k += 1

   if k > n/2:
       return 1

   else:
       return 0

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       input = sys.stdin.read()
       data = list(map(int, input.split()))
       n = data[0]
       a = data[1:]
       m = merge_sort(a)
       print (get_major_element(m,n))
   ```

The result I get is invalid.
I guess, that I can do that without initial sorting, but I can't get which step should I rewrite! Can anyone help please?

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using `sorted` or `list.sort`? I guess that this is an assignment. If the assignment is about sorting, you should state that in your question (so that we do not propose different approaches); if it is not about sorting and you are merely using a sort to solve the problem, just use a bultin sort function.

Comment: Also, have you tried using `collections.Counter(the_list).most_common(1)`?

Comment: There's a well-known standard algorithm that solves this in a single pass over the array and O(1) space. http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html

Answer (score 2):

Divide your array into two halves, the left half and the right half. Note that if an element is the majority of the whole array, then it's the majority of at least one of the halves.

So to find the majority of an array, recursively find the majority of both halves, and then with a single pass on the array count how many times both of the candidates appear in the whole array, to check which of them is the majority of the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a set of unique elements and count their occurrences in the original list, then compare the biggest value with the list length:

```
def get_major_element(my_list):
    available_items = set(my_list)
    max_count, max_item = max((my_list.count(item), item) for item in available_items)
    return max_item if max_count > len(my_list)/2 else None
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7b8fh7)

Comment: That what I thought firstly, but would be efficient solution. I need to implement divide-and-conquer algorithm here

Comment: What is that divide-and-conquer algorithm? It would be useful if you could explain that so we know what you want.

Comment: @ByteCommander a "divide and conquer" algorithm is one where the problem can be recursevely cut in smaller sub-problems, until reaching a simple case for each sub-sub-sub-problem, and combine them all back into one global solution. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reason that you aren't using built in sort and counting mechanisms pointed out by others, this will do it in a single pass without using anything but very basic datatypes.  Many of the built in operations may contain loops that could make them O(n**2) in the worst case.

```
def getMajor(L):
    best = None
    elements = {}
    for element in L:
        elements[element] += 1
        if elements[element] > elements.get(best, 0):
            best = element

    if elements.get(best, 0) > len(L)/2:
        return best, elements.get(best, 0)
    else:
        return None, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

check moore's algorithm, it works in two pass and finds majority element in O(N)

Or simply sort array and element on middle index (startIndex + endIndex)/2 should be majority element. (if there is majority element at all in array).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def get_majority_element(a, left, right):
    if left == right:
        return -1
    if left + 1 == right:
        return a[left]


    left_elemt = get_majority_element(a,left,(left + right - 1) // 2 + 1)
    right_elemt = get_majority_element(a,(left + right - 1) // 2 + 1,right)

    l_count = 0
    for i in range(left,right):
        if a[i] == left_elemt:
            l_count += 1
    if l_count > (right - left)//2:
        return left_elemt

    rcount = 0
    for i in range(left, right):
        if a[i] == right_elemt:
            rcount += 1
    if rcount > (right - left) // 2:
        return right_elemt

    return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n, *a = list(map(int, input.split()))
    if get_majority_element(a, 0, n) != -1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

I spent a lot of time on this one. had the same question and confusion as you. It appears that the function for middle should be (left + right - 1) // 2 + 1 (credit to mablatnik's git ) (altho I have not figure out why yet)

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me in java

```
k=1;
for(c=0;c<n-1;c++){
    if(array[c]==array[c+1])
      k+=1;

    else k=0;


    if (k > n/2){
      System.out.print("1");
      break;

    }
  }
  if (k <=n/2){
      System.out.print("0");
}
```

Comment: Question is about Python, and your code assumes that the array is sorted, which is not stated in the question.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56161162/13467399

Thanks for your post, mate. I was scratching my head over the problem. I see that you were wondering why the author finds the mid point by (left + right - 1) // (2 + 1).

It's because the "right" here is taking the size the array and arrays always start at 0 not 1, that answers for adding 1 in the divisor.

Actually, the mid point can be calculated using (left + right) / 2.

Sorry that I can't comment in your post since I don't have the privileges.

Comment: It is not an answer to the question, it should be a comment on the answer you refer to. Also, beware of parentheses because in this context `(2 + 1)` is incorrect due to operator precedence, which was correct in their answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t comment in his post since I don’t have enough the privilege points. And thanks for pointing out what I got wrong in my answer.